# Map Alt-c to Ctrl-u

Tags: bash, keyboard, bind, inputrc

Im writing the **~/.bashrc** file.
I want to bind, Alt-c to Ctrl-u.
So that when I press Alt-c. The functionality of Ctrl-u should happen.
Ctrl-u clears the text on the terminal.
So Alt-c should now do that.

I have the following text:

```
# Avoids default mapping.
# set bind-tty-special-chars off
# Solves error: 'bind editing not enabled.'
# But prevented me from using Control-p/n.
set -o vi; 
# Up Directory (Alt-j)
bind '"\ej": "cd ..;\r"';
```

Which successfully binds alt-j to the code *"cd ..;"*
But I don't know how to map alt to a Ctrl mapping.

It probably has something to do with the "*set -o vi*". But I can't remove it without getting the bind error.
Also, unsetting "*set -o vi*" causes side effects such that i cannot press tab in the terminal anymore. They also say that its just a choice between emacs and vi, so I think for my future its best if I could simply have set -o vi on, for im completely in Vim.

I have also tried having the following before the set -o vi, it doesn't work.

```
# Clear Text (Alt-c)
bind '"\ec": "Control-u:"';
```

But anyways.
How do I map Alt-c to Ctrl-u?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> invokes the `unix-line-discard` widget in both `vi` command and insert modes:

```
bash-5.2$ set -o vi
bash-5.2$ bind -pm vi-command | grep -iw c-u
"\C-u": unix-line-discard
bash-5.2$ bind -pm vi-insert | grep -iw c-u
"\C-u": unix-line-discard
```

You'd bind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to do the same by either making it invoke the same widget:

```
bind -m vi-command '"\ec": unix-line-discard'
bind -m vi-insert  '"\ec": unix-line-discard'
```

Or making it translate to the `^U` character:

```
bind -m vi-command '"\ec": "\C-u"'
bind -m vi-insert  '"\ec": "\C-u"'
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use  `bind` to bind a key to a readline function. `bind -p` lists all the current bindings, and should include:

```
"\C-u": unix-line-discard
```

so if you want to call that same function, use

```
bind '"\ej":unix-line-discard'
```